# ListData.svc does not exist when connecting to web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have recently been developing a suite of WCF/JSON web services. These all work fine when running in my development environment. In trying to get it running on the test environment I have been getting the following error.

> The service '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc' does not exist.

I have added the (hosted) web service as a new service reference which appears to work fine and said web service does not connect to any other services, it simply performs data look ups using linq2sql.

This is the full event log message, when a request is made from a (local) WPF client:

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/11454272 
>   Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service
>   '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc' does not exist. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service
>   '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc' does not exist.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)  Process Name: w3wp  Process ID: 3768

Answer (score 2):

By enabling includeExceptionDetailInFaults I was managed to get a much more appropriate response, it was simply a database connection issue in the end.